# How to access value returned by a callback function in outer scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback, closures

I am having troubles accessing values from within a callback function in parent/outer scope. Basically I want to access the data that the following `s3.getObject()` function fetches and use it in outer scope (last line).

I have the following javascript code to fetch some data from AWS:

```
const Papa = require('papaparse'); 
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

AWS.config.update({
    //ids
})

const s3 = new AWS.S3()


/* actual parameters should go here */
const params = {
  Bucket: "test-ashish-2019", 
  Key: "dummy.csv"
};

const parseOptions = {
  header: true,
  dynamicTyping: true
}

s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
if (err)  console.log(err, err.stack);
//   else {console.log(data)};
else {
    const csv = data.Body.toString('utf-8'); 
    const headers = 'id,start,end,count';
    const parsed = Papa.parse(headers + '\n' + csv, parseOptions);
    var csvdata = parsed.data;
    console.log(csvdata); //this is working as expected
    }

});

console.log(csvdata); //not working as expected
```

How do I make the last line work?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access that variable outside of the callback scope because the callback is happening asynchronously (your last line is actually being called before `csvdata` gets set by the callback).

You'll have to pass that data along a promise chain (or use async/await) to use it outside the callback context.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your code executes immediately before the callback is called and s3.getObject returns a promise so you can utilize the promise this way:

Refactor your code to this:

```
const getS3Object = async () => {

const data = await s3.getObject(params);
const csv = data.Body.toString('utf-8'); 
const headers = 'id,start,end,count';
const parsed = Papa.parse(headers + '\n' + csv, parseOptions);
var csvdata = parsed.data;
console.log(csvdata); //this is working as expected
}

console.log(csvdata); //will work
```